# How to exclude unpublished pages from DjangoCMS menu?

Tags: django-cms

I have a DjangoCMS website to administer. I need to publish a page only for EN language. The issue is that there are 3 more languages, and when I publish the page only for EN, it becomes available in other language menus as well. The menu item name is in English which makes the website look very unprofessional. Is this a DjangoCMS specific weakness of menu logic or poorly coded website?

I found that there are others reporting this issue too - https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/6004

How can I exclude unwanted pages to appear on the menu of other languages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to change at settings.py following:

'hide_untranslated': **True**,

```
CMS_LANGUAGES = {
    1: [
        {
            'code': 'en',
            'name': gettext('English'),
            'fallbacks': ['de', 'fr'],
            'public': True,
            'hide_untranslated': True,
            'redirect_on_fallback': False,
        },
        {
            'code': 'de',
            'name': gettext('Deutsch'),
            'fallbacks': ['en', 'fr'],
            'public': True,
        },
        {
            'code': 'fr',
            'name': gettext('French'),
            'public': False,
        },
    ],
    2: [
        {
            'code': 'nl',
            'name': gettext('Dutch'),
            'public': True,
            'fallbacks': ['en'],
        },
    ],
    'default': {
        'fallbacks': ['en', 'de', 'fr'],
        'redirect_on_fallback': True,
        'public': True,
        'hide_untranslated': False,
    }
}
```

http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#cms-languages

Answer (score 1):

@lazdins This could be fixed in 3.7.1: "Fixed a bug where the menu would render draft pages even if the page on the request was a public page. This happens when a user without change permissions requests edit mode."
https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.rst#371-2019-11-26

3.4 I also no longer supported, It is advised that you move to 3.7 as it is an LTS release that is currently supported and the recommended version at the time of my comment: https://www.django-cms.org/en/roadmap/

I have posted this into the issue as well. https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/6004#issuecomment-702052627

Comment: @twelvell Please update me here or in the issue if 3.7 is the solution to the fix.

Comment: Upgraded to 3.7.4 - still the same